# Windows 10: What versions of msxml are present on fresh install?

Tags: windows, msxml

MSXML 4 is [not pci compliant](https://community.intuit.com/questions/1110103-xml-parser-vulnerability-introduced-by-installation)

Out of box Windows 10, that is msxml 6 only, correct?

Comment: I haven't checked yet, but it seems very unlikely that MSXML 3 isn't also present.  It has been a recommended universal fallback version for quite some time and probably gets security fixes as required.  Removing it would break a large number of products.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is:

Out of box, Windows10 includes:

msxml3.dll
msxml6.dll